# How can I install pf-kernel on 14.04?

Tags: kernel

There is an article here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/get-better-linux-desktop-performance.html

But it is not updated. Does anyone have an idea how I can do it for 14.04? Thank you!

Comment: Care to add that as an answer? And I will mark it as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Install Pf-Kernel By following: (If it is not available with PPA)

First Download deb packages,

```
linux-headers-3.14.0-pf1+_3.14.0-pf1+-10.00.Custom_i386.deb
linux-image-3.14.0-pf1+_3.14.0-pf1+-10.00.Custom_i386.deb
```

Then install packages by `sudo dpkg -i` and reboot.

Instruction for 32 & 64 bit is given on [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-pf-kernel-3-14-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-their-derivative-systems/).